# Python program to calculate capacity of a box using inheritance

Tags: python

I am learning python and I can't figure out an inheritance program to calculate the number of small boxes a big box can contain. I have a partial code that was given as part of an assignment but unfortunately the solution has not been given. The following is the code given :

```
class Box:
    def getVolume(self):
        vol= self.length*self.breadth* self.height
        return vol
    def __init__(self, length, breadth,height):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
        self.height = height

class BigBox(Box):
    def __init__(self,length,breadth,height):
         Box.__init__(self,length,breadth,height)
         def getCapacity(self, sBox):
```

**Requirement:** A big box can contain small boxes.

**Q:** Write logic for function getCapacity(self,sBox) in BigBox that returns capacity(number of small boxes it can contain).

Formula for Capacity = BigBox volume / Small box volume.

Test your code with following:

```
smallBox = Box(1,1,1)
bigBox = BigBox (4,4,4)
capacity = bigBox.getCapacity(smallBox)
print("capacity:",capacity)
```

Can anyone help me out, please? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have "Formula for Capacity = BigBox volume / Small box volume", you can simply define the `BigBox.getCapacity` method as:

```
def getCapacity(self, sBox):
    return self.getVolume() // sBox.getVolume()
```

With your sample input, this outputs the following:

```
capacity: 64
```